# Force user to select an option from data list

Tags: jquery, html, jscript, html-input, html-datalist

I have a datalist input, with several options, and I want to force user to select an option **from list.**
How can I do that? Here there is an example, but in this way I can write anything in input.

**HTML**

```
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
<input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" id="myBrowser" /></label>
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  <option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>

<button>get value</button>
```

**JavaScript and jQuery**

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    console.log($('#myBrowser').val());
});
```

Sorry for my bad english.

https://jsfiddle.net/pewfp0wf/

Comment: use a `select` tag

Comment: @JoshKisb I already tried but I need search if I use `select` tag.

Comment: @APAD1 I want the user to necessarily select an option without being able to write anything else.

Comment: Check the question I linked above. If you want to use a `select` element with search capabilites, look into a solution like [Select2](https://select2.org/)

Comment: @APAD1 Yes but i think it's not the best way to do it, because I have a lot of options.
I'll look Select2, thanks.

Comment: you want your users to be limited by options but have them not know the exact limitations??? this will get super annoying especially if the poor user makes a typo

Comment: @JoshKisb Sorry but I can't understand you. 
Maybe the best solution is Select2.

Comment: yes a select tag is the solution we have all been saying. anyway you now know what to do